# Position of "toujours" and "encore" in negation

Tags: négation, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

From [Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/attentat-berlin/article/2016/12/23/ce-que-l-on-sait-des-victimes-de-l-attentat-de-berlin_5053240_5051632.html):

> (1) Trois des douze personnes tuées lundi soir ... n’ont **toujours** pas été identifiées.

Does *toujours* always need to be placed before *pas*, or does any other placement work?

> (2) Trois des douze personnes tuées lundi soir ... n’ont pas **toujours** été identifiées.
>
> (3) Trois des douze personnes tuées lundi soir ... n’ont pas été **toujours** identifiées.
>
> (4) Trois des douze personnes tuées lundi soir ... n’ont pas été identifiées **toujours**.

If we change *toujours* to *encore*, does only position (2) work because of the combination *pas encore*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When meaning "not yet", you will always say "toujours pas" or "pas encore". So only (1) is correct.

"Pas toujours" is also grammatically correct but has another meaning - literally "not always".